# How to fix vba type mismatch?

Tags: vba

I have a compile error message `byref argument type mismatch` pointing to rg1 where the HTML is.

Could you please help?

```
Sub email_multi_ranges()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rgl As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range, rg4 As Range
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set rg1 = locate(1, 1, "Countries")
Set rg2 = locate(11, 1, "Countries")
Set rg3 = locate(3, 1, "Sheet2")
Set rg4 = locate(15, 2, "Sheet2")

str1 = "<BODY style=font-size:12ptsfont-family:calibri>" & _
"Hello Team, <br><br> Please see the figures below.<br>"

str2 = "<br>Best regards,<br>Tam"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "test.com"
    .cc = "test1.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Country Info"
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = str1 & RangetoHTML(**rg1**) & RangetoHTML(rg2) & _
                RangetoHTML(rg3) & RangetoHTML(rg4) & str2 & .HTMLBody
                
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function locate(y1 As Long, x1 As Long, sh As String) As Range
Dim y2 As Long, x2 As Long
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh).Activate

y2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(y1, x1), Cells(y1, x1).End(xlDown))) + y1 - 1
x2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(y1, x1), Cells(y1, x1).End(xlToRight))) + x1 - 1

Set locate = Sheets(sh).Range(Cells(y1, x1), Cells(y2, x2))

End Function
```

Comment: Your `Dim rgl` at the top is a lower case L, rather than the intended `1` by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you declared the variables as `Dim rgl As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range, rg4 As Range` but then you reference `Set rg1 = locate(1, 1, "Countries")`

If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of the `sub`, it'll throw an error because you've not declared `rg1`.

Just change `rgl` to `rg1`, and it should work.

Best practice going forward may be to always use `Option Explicit` to force variable declaration.

Comment: perfect. It works. Thanks a lot Rohit for your valuable time & quick help. You're SUPER GENIUS !!

Comment: Thank you so much spikey_richie for your valuable time & quick help. You're SUPER GENIUS !! Thanks millions

Comment: Please tick the green tick under this answer, to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I am new. are we allowed to give the super user who helps with the problems scores/rating? if so, how? thanks a lot

Comment: Sort of. Users get reputation for providing an answer marked as correct by the person asking the question, and we also get reputation for having answers up-voted.